# LinkedIn redirect uri not working with dynamic url (was previously working)

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, hello.js, social-authentication

I've got a problem that I'm using social authentication in my web app and the app will have several instances. The URL has always been dynamic but was recently reformatted, therefore the redirect_uri now seems to need to be different each time as I keep getting the 'invalid redirect_uri' error.

Effectively I have a website url of:

```
http://www.website.com/static_subdomain/<id that is dynamic>
```

Before it was:

```
http://www.website.com/#/<id that is dynamic>
```

I had expected that I'd be able to put

```
http://www.website.com/ or http://www.website.com/static_subdomain/
```

in as the Authorized Redirect URL, but LinkedIn isn't happy and seems to require an exact match. Yet with the previous format it was perfectly happy with those redirect_uri's.

It's also worth noting that Facebook and Google authentication both work fine on the same app with this redirect uri:

```
http://www.website.com/static_subdomain/
```

Am I likely to be doing it wrong on LinkedIn or do I need to use the full URL every time for LinkedIn? If so... why was it working before when we had a # in the URL?